# Multiprocessing & multithreading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

What's the best approach to multithread / multiprocess the following snippet of code?

Summary: prime numbers are found from 3...and onwards. Each prime is then appended to the array `primes[]`, wherein, the gap to the previous prime is found. The longest consecutive sequence of even numbers is printed to the console.

I have read other questions & notes about this topic, but I'm confused & not sure where to start.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()
gap = 0
primes = []
for i in range(3,999999999,2):
    prime_check = True
    for j in range(0,int(len(primes)/2.9)):
        if(i%primes[j] == 0):
            prime_check = False
            break
    if(prime_check):
        primes.append(i)
    #print("{0} is {1}".format(i,prime_check))
    if(len(primes)>1):
        if(primes[-1] - primes[-2] > gap):
            gap = primes[-1] - primes[-2]
            end = timer()
            print("Gap: {0} ({1}, {2}) Time: {3:.2f}s".format(gap,primes[-2],primes[-1],end-start))
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is calculating the prime numbers, creating a queue of every two sequential primes of the interval and then creating threads to calculate the gaps. Since calculating prime numbers is a sequential process, it's harder to use threads on that part.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from queue import Queue
import threading as th

start = timer()
NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 8
queue = Queue() 
gap = 0
primes = []

def calculate_primes():
    for i in range(3,999999999,2):
        prime_check = True
        for j in range(0,int(len(primes)/2.9)):
            if(i%primes[j] == 0):
                prime_check = False
                break
        if(prime_check):
            primes.append(i)
            if len(primes) > 1:
                queue.put((primes[-1], primes[-2]))

# Create worker threads
def create_workers():
    for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
        t = th.Thread(target=work)
        t.start()

# Do the next job in the queue
def work():
    while not queue.empty():
        integers = queue.get()
        get_gap(integers[0], integers[1])
        queue.task_done()

def get_gap(x, y):
    global gap
    if(x - y > gap):
        gap = x - y
        end = timer()
        print("Gap: {0} ({1}, {2}) Time: {3:.2f}s".format(gap,y,x,end-start))

calculate_primes()
create_workers()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it.